# PHP dropdown to query for another dropdown to query for results

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Right! I'm a complete PHP noob but have managed to completely blag/copy/paste/graft together some PHP that queries what I want it to query and return me a dropdown.

Now. I can bastardise this for another dropdown. HOWEVER. This dropdown should be returning results based on an array returned from the first query.

AND. Finally once this dropdown has been selected it should be printing the results in a table below.

I understand that I should be using Javascript to temporarily store the values returned by the dropdowns.

So it goes as such, I have three queries that all work in MySQL:

```
select id, name, replace(replace(arrange, 'c,', ''), '|', ',')
from cats
limit 10;
```

This query now returns the "arrange" in an array-friendly format which contains the subcategories which I simply copy and paste, but for this want to return as a string and query.

```
select id, name, Group_concat(replace(replace(arrange, 'i,', ''), '|', ',')) As          Products_in_Category from cats
where id in (ARRAY FROM PREVIOUS QUERY REPLACE);
```

This now returns a massive array, that you guessed it, I want to define as a string and query to return for the final query.

```
select p.id,substring(c.name, 1, 60) As Name, c.code, sum(qty) As Sold
from cart c
join prods p on c.item = p.id
and order_status = ('Processed Order')
and p.id in ([ARRAY RETURNED FROM PREVIOUS GROUP_CONCAT)
group by code
order by sold desc
```

So, the code I have for the PHP is:

```
<?php  
$host = '';
$user = '';
$pass = '';
$db = '';

//Database Connection
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db)
or die ('Could not select database ' . mysql_error());

// SQL QUERY TO NAME 
$sql = "select id, name, replace(replace(arrange, 'c,', ''), '|', ',')
from kcommerce_cats
where arrange like ('c,%')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='type'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';

}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

So how do I now select the replace as a string.

How do I then query that replace as the In for the 2nd dropdown.

And from there, how the devil should I declare the group_concat as a string to be queried for the final in.

Add to that I would love to be able to put all that in an HTML table.

I am asking a lot here but have the principles of what I want in my head, just not the PHP ability!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I haven't managed to work out the dropdown/select side of things, but I have managed to answer the question of how to pass a result from one query and then query against that - also I have managed to print the results in an HTML table.

So, in order for the querying of the categories which will eventually be the basis of the whole page and its' dropdowns:

```
$query = "select id, name, replace(replace(arrange, 'c,', ''), '|', ',') As Arrange
from cats
where arrange like ('c,%') limit 10";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
$message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
die($message);
}
```

The above is doing the first query in preparation for the storing of the result as a string.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$arrange = $row['Arrange'];
}
echo $arrange;

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Now this is saying lookup the value of arrange from the first query, the echo prints it out so you can confirm the values returned. The important part is the $arrange that is now in the code to store that array.

```
//Query Subcategories

$query = "select id, name, Group_concat(replace(replace(arrange, 'i,', ''), '|', ',')) As     Products from cats
where id in (".$arrange.")";
```

This is the subcategory query with the important addition of querying against the results from $arrange.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
$message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
die($message);
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$prodsarray = $row['Products'];
}
echo "<br>";
echo $prodsarray;
```

I have then repeated the process as above, returning the Group Concat as a string which can then be used as per the first line of the 2nd query above.

```
$query = "select p.id As ID,substring(c.name, 1, 100) As Name, c.code As Code, sum(qty) As     Sold, 
p.price As Price, format(p.price*1.2,2) As VAT, p.rrp As RRP, p.cost As Cost
from cart c
join prods p on c.item = p.id
and order_status = ('Processed Order')
and p.id in (".$prodsarray.")
and date_ordered < now()-interval 3 month
group by code
order by sold desc";

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$result) {
$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
$message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
die($message);
}
```

The next step is to echo the results from this query into a table.

```
echo "<table class='equalDivide' cellpadding='0'cellspacing='0' width='100%' border = '3'><tr>";
echo "<td width = '5%' align='center'>ID</td>";
echo "<td width = '35%'align='center'>Name</td>";
echo "<td width = '15%' align='center'>Code</td>";
echo "<td width = '7.5%' align='center'>Sold</td>";
echo "<td width = '7.5%' align='center'>Price</td>";
echo "<td width = '7.5%' align='center'>VAT</td>";
echo "<td width = '7.5%' align='center'>RRP</td>";
echo "<td width = '7.5%' align='center'>Cost</td>";
echo "</tr></table><br>";
```

Above is the hardcoding of the field names.

```
 // Use result
 // Attempting to print $result won't allow access to information in the resource
 // One of the mysql result functions must be used
 // See also mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row(), etc.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<table class='equalDivide' cellpadding='0'cellspacing='0' width='100%' border = '1'><tr>";
echo "<td width = '5%'>".$row['ID']."</td>";
echo "<td width = '35%'>".$row['Name']."</td>";
echo "<td width = '15%'>".$row['Code']."</td>";
echo "<td width = '7.5%'>".$row['Sold']."</td>";
echo "<td width = '7.5%'>".$row['Price']."</td>";
echo "<td width = '7.5%'>".$row['VAT']."</td>";
echo "<td width = '7.5%'>".$row['RRP']."</td>";
echo "<td width = '7.5%'>".$row['Cost']."</td>";
echo "</tr></table>";
}
```

This is the loop that fills the table with the results, notice the ['Sold'] under row is whatI declared the row as in the select query.

Next step is to turn the first two queries into dropdown selects, then I am done! Boom!